# Is there a way to add material select option at the end of the list?

Tags: html, angular, angular-material

I want to whenever I have a , when I choose an option, add it at the end of the list, instead of placing it as its order...

You can check material's stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/angular/jdgkdlbeldj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fselect-multiple-example.ts

If I have this list:

```
toppingList: string[] = ['Extra cheese', 'Mushroom', 'Onion', 'Pepperoni', 'Sausage', 'Tomato'];
```

And I select initially Mushroom and Pepperoni ->`MyList = [Mushroom, Pepperoni].`

If I add a new option, such as Onion, I would like to be having MyList as:
`[Mushroom, Pepperoni, Onion]`, but I get it as `[Mushroom, Onion, Pepperoni]`.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Angular material [select](https://material.angular.io/components/select/api) provide sortComparator input property. It will accept comparater fuction to sort the selected value.

**component.html**

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-label>Toppings</mat-label>
  <mat-select [sortComparator]="sortComparator" [formControl]="toppings" multiple>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let topping of toppingList" [value]="topping">{{topping}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

**component.ts**

```
sortComparator(a:any, b:any){
    return 1;
  }
```

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7y29pv)

Comment: @EstebanChornet sortComparator is input property which accepts js Compare Function as a input, for more info: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_array_sort.asp

Comment: So I don't really need parameters at my component.ts? Just sortComparator() { return 1; } as we're forcing to always return 1...

Comment: Acutally comparison function receives two arguments, and should return 1 if the first argument should preceed the second, -1 if the second argument should preceed the first and 0 if they are equal.

Answer (score 1):

Instead using a form binding manually check when `selectionChange` event gets triggered and then compare the new selection with your saved selection. When a new selected element isn't selected in your list then push it into it when when in your new selection is an item missing remove this from your list.

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select (selectionChange)="changeMySelection($event)" [value]="myList">
     // your options ....
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```